# かっこ`[]`で囲まれた文字以外をマッチさせたい

Tags: 正規表現

かっこ`[]`で囲まれた文字以外をマッチさせたいのですが、わかりません。

`あいうえお[ほげ]かきくけこ[ふが]`

↓マッチさせる文字列

- `あいうえお`
- `かきくけこ`

Answer (score 4):

先読みを利用すれば出来ると思います。
マッチさせる箇所(A)を`[^\[\]]+`、させない箇所(B)を`\[[^\[\]]+\]`だとすると、先読みさせるにはA(?=B)、つまり`[^\[\]]+(?=\[[^\[\]]+\])`という形になります。これと末尾(もしくは全体)にマッチするパターンA$=`[^\[\]]+$`を組み合わせれば

```
([^\[\]]+(?=\[[^\[\]]+\])|[^\[\]]+$)
```

となります。

Answer (score 1):

> ↓マッチさせる文字列
>
> あいうえお
>   かきくけこ

厳密にこの２パターンだけをマッチさせたい場合は、単に

> (あいうえお|かきくけこ)

でいいです(POSIX正規表現の場合)。

正規表現は言語によって多少書き方が変わることもあるので、
できれば質問の際、使うプログラミング言語を明示したほう
がよいでしょう。

Comment: 回答有難うございます。
言語はrubyでgsubを使おうと思っています。
マッチさせたい部分は常に変わるのでその方法は使えなさそうです・・・

Answer (score 1):

”ほ”
”げ”
”ふ”
”が”
を除外したいのであれば
[^ほげふが]+

その質問では、具体的な一致条件、不一致条件が明確ではないので、
非常に答えずらいと思います。